# 3D histogram from a matrix of z-value

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, matplotlib-3d

I've searched in the forum, but I've found only similar but different answers and questions. I have a problem in plotting a 3D histogram starting from a matrix of z-values.

That's the matrix I obtained from previous operations:

```
[[  84.           80.76923077   68.05555556   56.57894737   60.
    44.7761194    55.2238806    39.0625       27.41935484   29.8245614 ]
 [  82.44274809   67.70833333   63.75         44.44444444   47.76119403
    33.33333333   22.78481013   19.23076923    9.21052632    2.63157895]
 [  53.33333333   61.76470588   48.64864865   34.61538462    0.
    16.66666667   0.            0.            0.            0.        ]
 [  48.           25.            0.            0.            0.         
    0.            0.             0.            0.            0. ]]
```

These are all z-values. The x and y values are simply their positions along the matrix.
I've just looked in the matplotlib pages but all the examples start from x,y-values. I have also looked in the forum but this problem is slightly different.

I'm trying with something like:

```
hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(20,20))
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1]+xedges[1:], yedges[:-1]+yedges[1:])
dx = xedges [1] - xedges [0]
dy = yedges [1] - yedges [0]
dz = hist.flatten()

ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, zsort='average')
```

But I'm in trouble with understanding how to put in x,y values.
Someone could help me?

UPDATE:

```
len_x, len_y = matrix.shape
x = np.linspace(0,len_x-1,len_x)
y = np.linspace(0,len_y-1,len_y)


# 3D PLOT:

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')    


hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x,y)
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1]+xedges[1:], yedges[:-1]+yedges[1:])

xpos = xpos.flatten()/2.
ypos = ypos.flatten()/2.
zpos = np.zeros_like(xpos)

dx = xedges [1] - xedges [0]
dy = yedges [1] - yedges [0]
dz = hist.flatten()

max_height = np.max(dz)
min_height = np.min(dz) 

ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, zsort='average')
```

Comment: How does the code you show relate to the data? The code would produce a 20 by 20 matrix, what you have is a 4 by 10 matrix. What exactly is the problem? Maybe you show exactly what you have tried, explicitely writing `x = ...`, `y= ...` etc in your code such that one understands what problem you face.

Comment: The problem is how to get x and y from the first matrix. The code I've shown is a trial that doesn't work...
I can't understand how to select x and y values from the initial matrix.

Comment: In your case x will be [0,1,2,...9], and y will be [0,1,2,3]. Then do `x,y = meshgrid(x,y)` to get the x and y matrix.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code, but it still not working...

Comment: Mhh, do you want to plot a histogram? Or do you want to plot the array you have on top of the question?

Comment: I want to plot a 3D histogram. x and y values are the matrix position, and the z-values (the height of each bin of the histogram) are the matrix values.

Comment: The z array you show is not a histogram, because it has negative values. So I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: Ok, you can consider the negative values like zeros in the histogram.

Comment: But there is no way `histogram2d` can produce negative numbers. So what is that line doing in your code?

Comment: I don't know, if I replace the negative numbers with zeros I will have the same problems... I only want to plot a 3d histogram with these values on the z-axis...

Comment: There is a [3D bar chart example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/3d_bars.html) on the matplotlib page. It does not use a histogram. But I somehow have the feeling that you don't want a histogram after all. In this demo, replace the data with your own data. If you then have a problem, show the complete code and a clear description of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you want to get. Try the following code as a starting point:

```
import numpy  as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

matrix = np.array([
    [84., 80.76923077, 68.05555556, 56.57894737, 60.,
     44.7761194, 55.2238806, 39.0625, 27.41935484, 29.8245614],
    [82.44274809, 67.70833333, 63.75, 44.44444444, 47.76119403,
     33.33333333, 22.78481013, 19.23076923, 9.21052632, 2.63157895],
    [53.33333333, 61.76470588, 48.64864865, 34.61538462, 0.,
     16.66666667, 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [48., 25., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0. ]])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

xpos = [range(matrix.shape[0])]
ypos = [range(matrix.shape[1])]
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xpos, ypos)
xpos = xpos.flatten('F')
ypos = ypos.flatten('F')
zpos = np.zeros_like(xpos)

dx = 0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
dy = dx.copy()
dz = matrix.flatten()

ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color='b', zsort='average')

plt.show()
```

Result is:

[image]

The code is a modification of [this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/hist3d_demo.html) from matplotlib.org.